# Laravel 7 Sending Emails through AWS SES

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, laravel-horizon

I have a very strange issue with sending emails through AWS SES. Some emails get sent and some don't get sent. All of my emails are running as background processes and when I check horizon it states the job have executed with no errors but I don't receive the emails.

On AWS there are no logs that track the emails that are sent either.

All emails were sending and now they are sent sporadically.

Would be great if I can find out what has happened to these emails.

Any help with this matter will be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Danny

Comment: there could me a myriad reasons for it, enable SES notification events and monitor bounced emails and try to find a pattern  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-using-event-publishing.html also, if this is an crucial business issue don't hesitate to contact AWS support if you are on a business/enterprise support plan

Comment: check try/catch exceptions, if no errors then use above suggested SNS topic way to publish the submit when sent,reject ..etc. sometimes emails can be rejected if the email receiver client thinks its spam/scam or some antivirus do that, when send in bulk

Comment: Sounds like they might be getting flagged as spam and filtered/blocked? https://www.mail-tester.com/ is handy.